# Reference request: smooth affine curves are planar

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X\rightarrow\mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{C}$ be an affine smooth morphism of relative dimension$\leq 1$. What is a reference for the fact that there exists a $\mathbb{C}$-locally closed immersion $X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$?

Comment: Z. Jelonek: *Smooth affine curves without embeddings into the affine plane*. Bull. Polish Acad. Sci. Math. 47 (1999), no. 4, 363–367.

Comment: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-similar-new-users